# How to include i18next locale files in ReactJS build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, deployment, path, react-i18next

I've searched plenty of posts with no luck in fixing my build problem.

I have two main problems

1. /public/locale/xx/xxx.json files paths are not included after building
2. The background images paths used in css are not working properly

Structure looks like this:

```
my-app
  public
    images
      image.jpg
    locale
      xx
        xxx.json
  src
```

And the background image url like `url(/images/image.jpg)`,

the url works good on dev, but in production/after build, it's relative to the `/` path, regardless of the `homepage` set in `package.json`

Same goes for locale files.

**PS**: `homepage` will not be `/`, let's say it will be `/myapp/`

My i18n file is like:

```
i18n
  use(Backend)
```

I have tried to set the backend settings to anything (`__dirname | env.PUBLIC_URL,...etc`), but nothing is working.

This seems to be a very common problem as i found a lot of posts on it everywhere, yet, there is no clear answers on how to set the relative paths correctly when running `npm run build`

If you have the knowledge, please give a *Step by Step guide for dummies* kind of answer.

Comment: Do you find the solution?

Comment: actually i did, i'll post it now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have managed to make it work using the following setup:

**Structure:**

```
├── public
|   ├── locales
|   |   ├─── ar
|   |   |    ├── errors.json
|   |   |    ├── general.json
|   |   |    └── warnings.json
|   |   └─── en
|   |        ├── errors.json
|   |        ├── general.json
|   |        └── warnings.json
├── src
|   ├── App.js
|   └── i18n.js
```

**i18n.js**

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n
  // load translation using xhr -> see /public/locales
  .use(Backend)
  // detect user language
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: false,
    defaultNS: 'general',
    ns: ['general', 'errors', 'warnings'],
    backend: {
      loadPath: `${window.location.pathname}locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`
    },
    load: 'unspecific',
    // special options for react-i18next
    // learn more: https://react.i18next.com/components/i18next-instance
    react: {
      wait: true
    }
  });

export default i18n;
```

**Component**

*namespaces are included per component as desired (anything other than '`defaultNS`' configuration)*

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{...}
export default withNamespaces('general', 'errors')(MyComponent)
```

Comment: so do you include your public folder to build/dist after webpack build your app. I currently use webpack-copy-plugin. And what is 'window.location.pathname', how webpack or server knows what is your public folder

Comment: you must include the public folder, this is where your index.html lives. As for the server (production), pathname would be something like `https://www.example.com/`. You can verify you have access to your locale files by typing the URL in chrome